# using shared folders on different network using windows 10

Tags: windows, networking

so I have a pc running windows 10 and it has shared folders setup. This pc is connected to my upstairs network. The file sharing is setup correctly and it works on the upstairs network. However on my downstairs network it doesn't want to work. I tried forwarding port 455 but my provider decides that blocking that port is a genius move. any ideas on how I can fix this issue?
All the routers in the network are connected to eachother. to access the upstairs network from outside, I always need to port forward trough the first router. The pc containing the shared folders is connected via ethernet cable to the upstairs network. The laptop will be moving between the upstairs and the downstairs network.

Scheme of network

[image: Scheme of network]

Comment: Please add a schema for your home network and how are the floors connected, including the two involved computers, routers, switches, access point, wired, wireless etc

Comment: So from the diagram, it looks like the traffic is entirely within your network? How does your ISP's port-blocking even affect it?

Comment: I assume the so-called "downstair network" and "upstair network" on your sketch represent the routers? If yes, is your "upstairs network" router set in bridge mode, or NAT mode ? If set in bridge mode, any PC on the downstairs network should be able to access the shared folder.

Comment: The router is set to nat mode, and yes the downstairs and upstairs network are the routers, the downstairs router is from the isp itself, and it blocks the forwarding of ports like 139 and 455, I can't use them as external or internal starting or ending ports. would there be another way then just using bridge mode?

Comment: Set the routers to manage the same subnet. You could limit each router to a sub-range inside the subset. Or, if for example all local subnets start with `192.168`, then set the netmask to `255.255.0.0`.

Comment: The bridge mode is the simplest solution, it will give you a unified network in the whole house. However, if for some reason you want/need to stick to the NAT mode, you have to configure a NAT rule on the upstair router: first you have to assign a static IP adress to the PC containing the shared folder, and then you forward the adhoc port to this adress. Then on the downstair router you have to assign a static IP address to the upstair router (say 192.168.1.20, but this can depend on the router): the PC will access the share by \\192.168.1.20\<share_name>

Comment: How is the upstairs router connected to the downstairs one? Which physical port to which physical port?

Answer (score 0):

## Bridge mode

The first and simplest solution is to set the upstair router in "Bridge mode": hence you will have a unified network in the whole house, with all devices able to see all others devices. This is downstair router that will attribute the IP adresses to all the devices, even to the ones connected to the upstair router.

## NAT mode

If for some (hopefully good) reason you do not want to use the bridge mode, then you have to set a NAT rule and assign some static IP adresses.

I am assuming below that both routers attribute IP adresses in the range `192.168.1.*`. If different, you just have to adapt the adresses. "PC1" is the PC that shares the folder, and "PC2" is the PC that wants to access the shared folder.

**On the downstair router:**

In the DHCP settings you assign a static IP address to the upstair router, say `192.168.1.20`

**On the upstair router:**

In the DHCP settings you assign a static IP address to PC1 , say `192.168.1.30` (it could be `192.168.1.20` again since the two networks are separate, but for sake of clarity I am using a different one).

In the NAT rules you forward the ports 139 and 445 to the address `192.168.1.30`.

**How to access**

PC1 will access the share by typing in the Explorer address field: `\\192.168.1.20\<share_name>`. Note the **20**, not 30, as PC1 cannot directly see PC2, he can only see the upstair router.